# Changing second level multiindex label when first level condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi index df with two levels of index like this:

```
    dfx = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 2),
                  index=[['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], ['aa', 'zz', 'gg', 'zz']],
                  columns=['data1', 'data2'])
    dfx

         data1     data2
a aa  0.847741  0.723235
  zz  0.236876  0.343141
b gg  0.759153  0.546190
  zz  0.481285  0.600514
```

I want to change the index labels only where the first level index has a specific value. i.e. Change the zz index only where the first label is b

```
Objective, get:

         data1     data2
a aa    0.847741  0.723235
  zz    0.236876  0.343141
b gg    0.759153  0.546190
  water 0.481285  0.600514
```

If I use `.rename()` all of the indexes matching get changed

```
dfx.rename(index={('zz') : 'water'}, inplace = True)
dfx

            data1     data2
a aa     0.847741  0.723235
  water  0.236876  0.343141
b gg     0.759153  0.546190
  water  0.481285  0.600514
```

I've tried the following code lines but this doesn't seem to do anything.

```
dfx.loc['b','zz'].rename(index={'zz' : 'water'}, inplace = True)
```

```
dfx.loc['b'].rename(index={'zz' : 'water'},  inplace = True)
```

I consulted the documentation and I've struggled to find a solution.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are not passing `level` parameter:   `dfx=dfx.rename(index={'zz' : 'water'},level=1)`

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I need to change 'zz' to 'water' *only* where the first level index is b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `MultiIndex.map`

```
d = {('b', 'zz'): ('b', 'water')}
dfx.index = dfx.index.map(lambda i: d.get(i, i))
```

---

```
            data1     data2
a aa     0.567847  0.844618
  zz     0.752874  0.794704
b gg     0.854358  0.512400
  water  0.237905  0.211369
```

Comment: This is the best working method, as it easily allows me to add other potential replacements that will definitely come up in the way. I just add these to d.

Answer (score 2):

You can try via `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples()`+list comprehension:

```
dfx.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [(x,y) if (x,y)!=('b','zz') else ('b','water') for x,y in dfx.index]
                                    )
```

OR

The other way is to reset the index then check the values and change it then set the index back:

```
dfx=dfx.reset_index()
dfx.loc[(dfx['level_0'].eq('b') & dfx['level_1'].eq('zz')),'level_1']='water'
dfx=dfx.set_index(['level_0','level_1']).rename_axis(index=[None,None])
```

Comment: This works too, however I'd rather not reset the index as part of my previous code and data wrangling has multiple index resetting. I did not specify this before and not think about it until after I saw your response. But thanks for the answer!.

Answer (score 2):

Another similar way:

1: Create a dataframe from the Multiindex

2: conditionally assign values

3: Turn back to Multiindex and assign:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(dfx.index.tolist())
d.loc[d[0].eq("b")&d[1].eq("zz"),1]='water'
dfx.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(d,names=[None,None])
```